# Drop Down menu expanded by default (on front page)

Tags: menus, jquery, css, dropdown

For [this site](http://www.explainingprogress.com/) users seem to have difficulty finding the site's content that is accessible through the 'Data' drop down menu on the top left.

To improve this I would like to have this drop down menu expanded by default – but only on the front page.

By [this older (not WordPress related) StackExchange question (that is including a JSFiddle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18786546/creating-drop-down-menu-on-click-css) and some other comments I have learned that I should use jQuery. I tried my best but I have not been able to get it working at all on my site.

What are the CSS elements on my site that I have to address in the JQuery code? And where should I put this code? Would somebody be able to help me?

**Edit:**

Thank you very much user49916! This works! The problem that I encountered was that the second level children were also expanded by default. To hide them and then only show them on hover I added this:

```
/*Make the drop down menu expanded by default – on the front page*/
    .home ul#menu-all-descendants-as-submenus li ul {
        left: 0;
    }

    /*Make the drop down menu expanded by default and hide the sub-children – on the front page*/
        .home ul#menu-all-descendants-as-submenus.menu li ul ul {
            left: -999em;
        }
    /*Make the drop down menu expanded by default and show the sub-children on hover of menu – on the front page*/

        .home ul#menu-all-descendants-as-submenus.menu li ul li:hover>ul {
            left: 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest I think you can just use some custom css to get the job done. Wordpress gives the homepage a custom body class of home. so if we use that and dig down in the css to the first menu and move it over into view you should be good.

```
.home .menu > li > ul {
left: 0;
}
```

and to get the hover state on the 'Data' link just use

```
.home #header .menu a {
background: #D3D3D3;

}
```

hope this helps!

Comment: +1. Ensure the Theme calls [`body_class()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) where appropriate, then rely on the [classes output on the site front page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class#Front_Page). Outside of that, this question is CSS/JS-related.

Comment: The theme is calling body_class() so he should be good to go.